# Visual Studio prebuild event not updating project before build

Tags: visual-studio, svn, msbuild, setup-deployment

The intent is that the latest files (checked in by the team members) are picked up for packaging when the build is created.

I have done the following steps:
1. In prebuild event (of setup project) added:
   svnupdate "Repository Path"/"Project Path" "Current Working Directory"/"Project Path"
2. Build the solution.

However during the msi creation latest files are not being picked up for packaging.

Any pointers to the same are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to answer without extra info: the principle listed should be working. Are you sure the latest files are effectively checkd out? You could try moving the svn update step to a seperate project and make sure that builds before the setup project.

Comment: @stijn Thanks for looking into the same.  What happens is that after the build has been created, a popup comes saying the following files have been modified. Do you want to take the latest of them?

Comment: Well that might be related, so you should fgure out where that popup comes from, VS doesn't have dialogs with such text (or, you are not quoting the text eactly - please post *exact* error messages always else it's really hard to guess what happens)